# MaterialTimePicker fragment not showing up

Tags: android, material-design, android-timepicker

New to android development. I want to take a time input from user using MaterialTimePicker and show the time in a `TextField`. MaterialTimePicker fragment is activated using a `onClickListener` on a `Button`. Also I'm developing in `java` and I'm not sure the documentation on material.io website is for java or kotlin.

```
 btnobj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            
            timepicker();
        }
    });

void timepicker(){
    MaterialTimePicker picker = new MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H)
            .setTitleText("Select Start Time")
            .setHour(12)
            .setMinute(10)
            .build();
    picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "starttime");
    txtfieldobj.setText(String.valueOf(picker.getHour())+" : "+String.valueOf(picker.getMinute()));
}
```

ERROR: Currently when I run this code after I click the button a blank page appears for a second and then it goes back to the parent activity.

Comment: why don't you try using a YouTube tutorial?

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal I tried that. In the tutorial they used val instead of MaterialTimePicker which im assuming is for kotlin. Otherwise I basically copied the same code. I couldnt find other videos for MaterialTimePicker using Java.

Comment: I checked your code its working fine for me . Check the error logs or try in some other device once ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example, and your problem is that you need to delete this line

```
txtfieldobj.setText(String.valueOf(picker.getHour())+" : "+String.valueOf(picker.getMinute()));
```

because it crashes the app with this [image]

And if you want to show the date and time after clicking OK, here the code:

```
private final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());

    void timepicker() {
        MaterialTimePicker picker = new MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
                .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H)
                .setTitleText("Select Start Time")
                .setHour(12)
                .setMinute(10)
                .build();
        picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(dialog -> {
            int newHour = picker.getHour();
            int newMinute = picker.getMinute();
            DashBoardActivity.this.onTimeSet(newHour, newMinute);
        });
        picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "starttime");
    }

    private void onTimeSet(int newHour, int newMinute) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, newHour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, newMinute);
        cal.setLenient(false);
        String format = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
        txtfieldobj.setText(format);
    }
```

Comment: you are not preferred to send images of code. Just copy and paste it here

Comment: Thank you, after commenting the txtview.setText my timepicker fragment show up . I just realized i only declared the txtfieldobj in the current scope of the object as i had initialized it in a different function.